# How to construct a pd.Series of a string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

how can i construct a pd.Series object from the string (imported as a txt file) that contains each cell as a data field?

string:

```
 'Hegselmann, R. (2012). Thomas C. Schelling and the Computer: Some Notes on Schelling’s Essay „Letting a Computer Help with the Work“. Journal of Artificial Societies and Social Simulation, 15(4). http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/15/4/9.html\nDowney, A. (2012). Think Python. How to Think Like a Computer Scientist. O’Reilly Media, Incorporated. http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html\nBird, S., Klein, E., & Loper, E. (2009). Natural Language Processing with Python—Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit. O’Reilly Media. https://sites.google.com/site/naturallanguagetoolkit/book'
```

First I change the file to a csv

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_fwf('E1_TM_1.txt')
    df.to_csv('E1_TM_1.csv')
```

If i want now to present it as a vector (is this the right term?)
It should just look like a simple table. The first column start with the index 1, the second column contains each References from the string.

I've tried the code, but it's not look like i want to.

```
pd.read_fwf('E1_TM_1.csv', encoding='utf8', index_col=0)

,"Hegselmann, R. (2012). Thomas C.","Schelling and the Computer: Some Notes on Schellingâ€™s Essay â€žLetting a Computer Help with the Workâ€œ. Journal of Artificial Societies and Social Simulation, 15(4). http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/15/4/9.html"
0,"Downey, A. (2012). Think Python.","How to Think Like a Computer Scientist. Oâ€™Reilly Media, Incorporated. http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html"
1,"Bird, S., Klein, E., & Loper, E.",(2009). Natural Language Processing with Pythonâ€”Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit. Oâ€™Reilly Media. https://sites.google.com/site/naturallanguagetoolkit/book
```

Furthermore the encoding to utf8 didn't work on the full string.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all I recommend you to split string using ' ':

```
string1 = "Hegselmann, R. (2012). Thomas C. Schelling and the     Computer: Some Notes on Schelling’s Essay „Letting a Computer Help with the Work“. Journal of Artificial Societies and Social Simulation, 15(4). http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/15/4/9.html\nDowney, A. (2012). Think Python. How to Think Like a Computer Scientist. O’Reilly Media, Incorporated. http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html\nBird, S., Klein, E., & Loper, E. (2009). Natural Language Processing with Python—Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit. O’Reilly Media. https://sites.google.com/site/naturallanguagetoolkit/book."
list_string =string1.split(' ')   
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
np.array(list_string)
```

Honestly, you describe task shortly... and I think, before creating array you could clean list and choose wordls what you need.

Comment: It's a task for my university course. 
The first part of the task is "Read the string object from the file E1_TM_1.txt." 
This worked out, and i copied the the string in my post. 
I'm quite sure, my prof don't want us, to split the string, because this one here is a short one. But in case of a very big one, it's not possible to split it, in an appropiate way. 

The second part of the task is "Construct a pd.Series object from the string that contains each cell as a data field."

I think it should look like a vector:
0 Hegselmann, [...]
1 Downey, [...]
2 Bird, [...]

Comment: Celina, if I understood you, your teacher wants  that you will create  pd.Series with Names of Authors.
For that task I recommend you to look 'Regular Expression'. And usefull tool for you will be [link](https://regex101.com/)
you could creat 'regular expression', check it in regex101. After that using loop to find all authors and using command: `code`pd.series`code` create  neccessary variable.